# GDB or Radare2?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, radare2

Should I use GDB or Radare2 for reversing an executable(I am a beginner)?
I try to programming in C and I got a SegFault. I want to Reverse Engineer it to get experience in Assembly and see where I get the SegFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend Radare2 because it's clearer than GDB and easier for beginners ;)

Comment: Thanks Now I can start Reverse Engineering with Radare2. Thanks :)

Comment: GDB is best for beginners. Radare2 is very complex.

Answer (score 6):

For *debugging* an executable you built from source yourself, GDB is intended as a debugger.  You can use `layout reg` to get a disassembly + registers view which can help understanding segfaults, if looking at C variables didn't help.

Debug info from compiling with `gcc -g` means you don't need to reverse-engineer anything, just use a normal debugger.  But to get experience in asm, using a debugger both ways (source view and asm view) can help you understand how the compiler used certain asm instructions to implement each C statement.  So you definitely want a debugger that can take advantage of debug info.  There are some GUI GDB front-ends, like https://www.gdbgui.com that can be easier to use than command-line GDB.

**But see also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more about seeing how C compiles to asm.**

I haven't used radare2.  I assume it has features that are good for intentionally-obfuscated executables without source, which is the opposite of what you have from compiling your own C programs with a normal compiler.

Comment: To be fair, many of features a RE-type tool provides are great for exploring non-obfuscated compiled binaries as well. One could also consider optimized binaries a type of obfuscation :). That said, I tried Radare2 for a while but never even to become competent. The learning curve is ... steep.